# Different colour on specific words in textfield. As3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a text-based RPG. Someone said it might be too hard so i should make keywords different colours. F.eks There is a locked chest, when you examine it you see that some of the *nails* are loose. You can get the loose *nail* and open the chest with it.

How do i change the colour of just that one word? Or how do i make just that one word italic?

Answer (score 1):

```
myTextField.htmlText = 'You can get the loose <font color="#ff0000">nail</font> and open the chest with it.'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `textfield` to display your text it accepts an **htmlText** input. Some (but not all) html formatting is acceptable there.